# SELECT sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou recebendo o erro: (node:20796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: _Acessojs2.default.query is not a function, tenho o arquivo de configuração do banco de dados:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const dbConfig = new Sequelize('acessomfrc', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA', {
    host: '192.168.0.25',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        useUTC: false,
    }
});

export default dbConfig;
```

meu arquivo acesso.js:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import dbConfig from '../db/config';

const acesso = dbConfig.define('acesso', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      nome: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      tag: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      ultimoacesso: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      }
});

export default acesso;
```

a parte para pegar os acessos:

```
const pegarAcessos = async (request, response) => {
    const acessos = await acesso.query("SELECT * FROM acesso");
    if(acessos) {
        response.send(200).send(acessos)
    }
    else {
        response.status(400).send({ error: 'Ocorreu algum erro.' })
    }
}
```

PS: Já tentei importar o dbConfig e substituir: `const acessos = await acesso.query("SELECT * FROM acesso")` por `const acessos = await dbConfig.query("SELECT * FROM acesso");` e também já adicionei o `{ type: dbConfig.QueryTypes.SELECT }` ou `{ type: acesso.QueryTypes.SELECT }`, mas quando o erro não é o mencionado lá em cima da mensage, quando passo `type: dbConfig.Query...` recebo só um OK de retorno (sem o response), ou passando `acesso.Query...` recebo o erro: `(node:27588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'SELECT' of undefined.`

PS2: Em outra rota, usando o método POST e com arquivos estruturados da mesma forma, tenho um create que funciona.

```
const adicionarTag = async (request, response) => {
    return await tag.create({
        tag: request.body.tag,
    }).then((tag) => {
        if (tag) {
            response.send(tag);
        } else {
            response.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao inserir.' });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu `acesso` é um modelo. *Raw queries* devem ser feitas numa instância do `Sequelize`. Veja a documentação do método [aqui](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query) e exemplos [aqui](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html).

```js
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("/* ... */");
```

Lembre que não faz sentido usar diretamente uma *Raw query* no modelo porque você irá escrever a query **inteira**, então você ainda teria que especificar a tabela dentro da query; por esse motivo o método está presente no Sequelize e não nos Model's :)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas porque passando const acessos = await dbConfig.query("SELECT * FROM acesso", { type: dbConfig.QueryTypes.SELECT }); e alterando o if para: if(acessos) {
        response.send(200).json(acessos[0])
    } recebo erro: (node:24992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11) sendo que minha rota está: router.use(authMiddleware); e router.get('/acessos', Controller.pegarAcessos);

Comment: O nome da tabela no seu banco é realmente `acesso`? Não está no plural? Dá uma conferida. Além do mais, para um `SELECT * ` você pode usar um `acesso.findAll()` que faz mais sentido

Comment: Resolvido, estava usando response.send(200) ao invés de response.status(200).send. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo. Ainda recomendo o uso do `acesso.findAll()`. O ORM (no caso, Sequelize) está aí para que você evite ao máximo usar *raw queries*.

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael!